# Need help in evaluating an indeterminate form ($0^0$) of a limit

Tags: calculus, indeterminate-forms

Let, $\Psi(x)= f(x)^{g(x)}$

Given, $\lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x)= 0, \lim_\limits{x\to a} g(x)=0$ and $\lim_\limits{x\to a} \Psi(x)$ exists.

If the mentioned conditions are guaranteed to be fulfilled, is it always true that
$$\lim_{x\to a} \Psi(x) =1 $$

Comment: $0^0 = 1$, but some prefer to say that it is not defined for the reason that will be apparent from the answers. For positive integers, $m$ and $n$, $n^m$ is the number of functions from a set of $m$ elements to a set of $n$ elements.

Comment: No. $0^0$ is an "indeterminate form", meaning precisely that there's more than one possibility for that limit.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, for me it is "determinate".

Comment: One of the most known indeterminate forms is the case $f(x)^{g(x)}$ where both $f$ and $g$ tend to zero. If $0^0$ were defined these forms were not "indeterminated".

Comment: @Alexey When you say $0^0=1$, is that because you have a combinatorial example in mind? Because it _is_ true that $\prod_{i\in\emptyset}0=1$. It makes sense to talk of $0^0$ if quantities are restricted to non-negative integers, but not to non-negative reals.

Comment: @Piquito, what do you mean by an "indeterminate form"? It is a slang expression which means that knowing that $f\to0$ and $g\to0$ is not enough to determine the limit of $f(t)^{g(t)}$. $1/0$ or $\sqrt{-1}$ are not "indeterminate forms", they are *not defined*.

Comment: @J.G., i consider it be the proper definition of $0^0$. All such definitions start from natural numbers, then extend to integers, then to rationals, then to reals. For natural numbers, $0^0=1$ is clearly a proper definition, just like $0! = 1$.

Comment: @Alexey it's only proper as a definition for $0^0$ when exponentiation is taken as a function $\text{^} : \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (or you could take $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$). When the exponent takes values in the continuum rather than integers, calling $0^0=1$ is problematic.

Comment: For continuous exponentiation I find it *much* more natural to define $a^x$ by a differential equation than by an extension of its definition for integer exponents, but I suppose that's a matter of preference.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp, i do not see any problem. On the other hand, if you do not define $0^0$, you have a problem with writing polynomial functions, because you cannot write something like $f(x) =\sum_{k=0}^na_nx^n$. But i am ok with considering it "undefined" while talking to people who strongly insist on its being undefined.

Comment: @Alexey So it's determinate for you, eh? Fine. Not clear what "for me determinate" means exactly, but in fact regardless of whether it's indeterminate "for you", it is in fact indeterminate. That word has a standard definition, and the definition doesn't say that an intdeterminate form is one that you personally feel is indeterminate. There is more than one possibiility for that limit, hence **by definition** it **is** indeterminate.What it is or is not "for you" is irrelevant.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp, i suppose that using differential equation is equivalent to writing $a^x =\exp(x\ln a)$. Indeed, I use that definition too, but it only works for $a>0$ and does not allow to defined $(-1)^{2}$. So i use different definitions for different cases, and in some cases these definitions consistently overlap.

Comment: @Alexey I am aware. That's exactly what I was talking about; any time the *exponent* is only taking on integer values (regardless of where the base is taken from) it makes perfect sense to say $0^0=1$ (in fact it is highly convenient and everyone does this all the time). The issue here is integer exponentiation and continuous exponentiation are *different functions*

Comment: @Alexey When you say "for me it s determinate" that makes exactly as much sense as when I say "for me, the derivative of $\sin(t)$ is $e^t$."

Comment: You can't directly extend the "repeated multiplication" definition even to rational exponents; you have the same issue of non-uniqueness as you have defining $a^x = \exp(x\ln a)$. Also, I'm a complex analyst by nature I see no problem with using this to define $(-1)^2$ :)

Comment: There's a difference between the value of $0^0$ which we can possibly define as $1$ and the limiting form $0^0$ which is an indeterminate form. Whether or not we define $0^0$ as $1$, $0^0$ as a limiting form is indeterminate.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, you are talking about *your* definitions. Not all mathematical terms have truly *standard* definitions, i might give you more examples, but $0^0$ is already an example. The definition you chose to use is *your* choice. A definition is not true or false, and a proper choice of definitions is a somewhat "meta-mathematical" question. I think i have not much more to say, but i may answer to some *mathematical* questions.

Comment: @Alexey Wise. Anyway, the issue of how to define $0^0$ is actually irrelevant to the question. If you define $0^0=1$, this makes the function $(x,y)\to x^y$ discontinuous at $(0,0)$, and hence knowing that both exponent and base approach $0$ is not enough to conclude the limit is $0^0=1$.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp, since i chose to restrict myself to single-values functions, i cannot define $a^b$ for negative $a$ and real $b$. Going from single-valued to multi-valued functions is a much more "breaking change" than going from naturals to reals for me. So i am ok to reconcile "natural" and "real" definitions, but i do not want to mix in multivalued functions. (Or functions on a covering Riemann surface).

Comment: @DarkMalthorp, i do not claim the contrary, see my first comment :).

Comment: @Alexey Indeed, we don't disagree. I was just trying to clarify things.

Comment: @Alexey No, I'm talking about _standard_ definitions. A definition that appears in close to every calculus book is standard - the fact that you didn't learn that definition in calculus doesn't change that.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, am not even going to discuss Calculus books. I do not wish to comment on "a definition that appears in close to every calculus book is standard." My comment was on mathematical definition, not on "Calculus definition". Calculus has little to do with defining $0^0$ for natural numbers. I believe that the author of a properly written Calculus books would not claim that $0^0$ is undefined. (But i may be wrong with this belief.)

Comment: @Alexey You're simply wrong. It _is_ a standard definition. Since the question was about that _limit_, the question of defining $0^0$ _for natural numbers_ is irrelevant. FInd a reference that agrees with you on this. Or find a mathematician who agrees with you. (You can find plenty of mathematicians right here...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, so, you prefer to define $0^0$ differently depending whether $0$ is natural or real, and you never write polynomial functions as $f(x) =\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k$. This is your choice. You claim your definition is standard because, apparently, most calculus books claim that $0^0$ is undefined (not just the it is an "indeterminate form," which is a slang expression for a true mathematical fact). I do not know if this claim can be verified even for Calculus books written in or translated into English, and not all Calculus books are equally good sources of definitions.

Comment: @Alexey "I do not know if this claim can be verified" you don't need to tell us this. I claim the definiton of "indeterminate form" is standard because it _is_. This is not a question that can be verified mathematically, it's an empircal question about how most mathmaticians use the language. You really should finda referece that agrees with you.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, you seem to be confused. We are not talking about "indeterminate forms" but about whether the result of the operation $0^0$ is defined (like whether $\sqrt{-1}$ or $1/0$ are defined). Do you know what the expression "indeterminate form" means and in what context it is used?

Comment: @Alexey Of course I write polynomials and power series that way! **In that context** $0^0$ is defined to equal $1$, as it has to be to allow us to use that notation. (Reference: page 10 of _Complex Made Simple_ by David C. Ullrich.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107765/discussion-between-alexey-and-david-c-ullrich).

Comment: @Alexey "We are not talking about "indeterminate forms" but about whether the result of the operation $0^0$ is defined". _You_ are talking about whether $0^0$ is undefined. That has nothing to do with the question. The question was whether that _limit_ must equal$1$; by definiton that's the same asking whether $0^0$ is an indeterminate form; defining ^0^0$ has nothing to dwith it.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, i am sorry, we must have misunderstood each other. I didn't say anything about the limit in my first comment. The original title read: "What is the value of $0^0$?" I was talking about the definition of the operation $0^0$, while you apparently were talking about a mathematical fact, and not about a definition. I do not understand though to what definition from calculus books you were referring... The fact that the form "$0^0$" is indeterminate is not a definition, it is a "theorem." Unless you wish to discuss in chat, i prefer to stop here.

Comment: @Alexey: I have translated literally "formas indeterminadas". I thought for your reply that it did not exist in English but I see in Google that it does exist. That exempts me from explaining what it is. Regarding $\sqrt{-1}$, this magnitude is absolutely determined and has great importance in mathematics as you know. Best regards.

Comment: @Piquito, i have explained in the previous comment that i was not talking about the "limit form $0^0$", i know that it is "indeterminate", but about $0$ to the power $0$ (please see my first comment and the original title of the question). $0^0$ can be naturally given a definite value, just like $0!$, $(-1)^{-1}$, or $1/2$, and unlike $0/1$ or $\sqrt{-1}$. (I define $\sqrt{x}$ as $y\ge 0$ such that $y^2 = x$, as i am not aware of any better definition but .)

Comment: @Alexey.- (I received by mail your reply) Suppose that $0^0=a$ where $0\lt a\lt \infty$ so you can take logarithms getting $0\cdot\log 0=0\cdot(-\infty)=\log a$. Thus $\log a$ could be indeterminated despite it is assumed a positive real. The situation cannot be compared with  $0!=1$ which is fully justified. On the other hand if you take $0^0=0$ then for all sequence $\{x_n\}$ tending to zero you would have a stationnary sequence $\{(x_n)^0\}$ tending to $1$. It is a particular reason among others, I guess, for $0^0=0$ be prohibited, is it not?. Best regards.

Comment: @Alexey.- I forgot to consider the possibility $0^0=1$ which could  be reasonable because it is the limit on the right of the function $x\to x^x$. Take again logarithms and see what happen without forgetting that x is not a discrete but continuous variable (it is not so for $0!$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

In fact, the limit can be anything. For example, if you want the limit to be $c\ne 1$: Let $a=0$, $f(x) = e^{-1/|x|}$, and $g(x) = (-\log c)|x|$, then $\Psi(x) = f(x)^{g(x)} = c$ for all $x\ne 0$, but $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} g(x) = 0$$

If $f$ and $g$ are *analytic* functions at $0$ then the answer is yes! In that case, one can write $f(x) = x^m \hat f(x)$ and $g(x) = x^n \hat g(x)$ for some positive integers $n,m$ and analytic functions $\hat f,\hat g$ that are nonzero at $0$. (In order for the limit to exist, you also need $\hat g(0) >0 $, but you did mention that a constraint in the question). In that case:$$
\Psi(x) = f(x)^{g(x)} = x^{m x^n g(x)} \hat f(x)^{x^n \hat g(x)} = (x^{x^n})^{m \hat g(x)} (\hat f(x)^{\hat g(x)})^{x^n} 
$$
By continuity, you can see that the limit of $(\hat f(x)^{\hat g(x)})^{x^n}$ as $x$ goes to $0$ must be $1$. Also, because the limit of $(x^{x^n})$ is $1$, and $m\hat g(x)$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $0$, you will also have the limit of the first term $(x^{x^n})^{m \hat g(x)}$ is $1$.

---

In general, the easiest way to evaluate limits of the form $0^0$ is by taking a logarithm:$$
\log (f(x)^{g(x)}) = g(x)\log f(x)\rightarrow 0\cdot(-\infty)
$$
and $0\cdot\infty$ is much easier to handle (e.g., change it to $\frac00$ or $\frac\infty\infty$ and use L'Hopital's rule).

Answer (score 2):

No

If $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)$ any strictly positive function which converges to zero. Then $\Psi = 0$

Answer (score 1):

No. See for instance $f(x)=e^{-(x-a)^{-2}}$ and $g(x)=-(x-a)^2\ln\lvert x-a\rvert$.

Answer (score 0):

Write the function as $$e^{g\log f}.$$ Then that's the same as determining $g\log f$ when both $f$ and $g$ vanish. But then $\log f=-\infty.$ So write it as $$\frac{\log f}{1/g}=\frac{-\infty}{\pm\infty}.$$ Clearly this can take any value at all, since there are infinitely many infinites. What obtains is given by the form of $1/g.$ For example, if $1/g=f,$ then the limit is $0.$ If $1/g=\log f,$ clearly it is $1.$ If $1/g=\sqrt {\log f},$ the limit is infinite, and so on.